# Sharing data between controllers in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I'm pulling my hair out over this.

The app I'm working on has a set of "alerts" that will be dynamically updated. I have the alerts template/controller/module all working fine. The alerts controller has a method for displaying the number of alerts that have not been dismissed. This works fine within the alerts template.

However, when I access that same method from another controller, it always returns 0.

[Here's a pastebin with the controllers, templates and model](http://pastebin.com/k1XEMzj7)

Thanks for any help!

**UPDATE**:

I discovered that if I actually load the alerts view, and then go back to the home view, the alerts controller starts returning the correct value. So apparently there is an issue with the fixture data not being ready when the menu controller accesses that method. I haven't yet been able to figure out why.

Comment: Ah, that's because your AlertRoute is setting up the model. If you just visit Home, Ember doesn't know to load up the model - even with the computed `remaining` property. At least this is my guess. Put some console.log in the `AlertsRoute.model` hook and see if it gets called.  ...I doubt it.

Comment: I updated my answer to show how you can setup your model within the `AlertsController`

Comment: You are correct that the model method of the AlertsRoute was not being called.

However, upon adding the init method you suggested, I discovered that while the init method is called before the remaining method is called, self.set('model', model); is not called until after the remaining method has already been called, causing it to still return 0;

Comment: You may have to change your `remaining` computed property to `.property('model.@each.isCompleted')`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to make a difference. I need to figure out how to load the data before the route is loaded.

Comment: No - this should work. Your `remaining` method should get called once it observes a change to it's dependent properties. Yes it might get called twice - once before init, and the again when its dependencies change. I think you need to fiddle with the `.property('...')` params to make Ember do this properly.

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate the help, but no it doesn't work. Maybe it should, but it doesn't.

I've tried it with many different params: 
.property('@each.isCompleted') 

.property('model.@each.isCompleted') 

.property('@each') 

.property('model') 

and even just .property()

It doesn't seem to have any effect. Remaining still only gets called before the model is set.

Comment: Is it possible to create your issue in ember.jsbin.com or jsfiddle? That way I can experiment with my ideas some more.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        this.render('menu', {
            into: 'home',
            outlet: 'alertsMenuItem',
            controller: 'alerts'
        });
    }    
});

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="home">
    <img {{bind-attr src=appInfo.headerImage}} id="header_image" alt="Header Image" />
    {{render "alerts" model}}
    <ul id="home_nav">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>
            {{outlet "alertsMenuItem"}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>   

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="menu"> 
    {{#link-to 'alerts'}}
        Alerts ({{remaining}})
    {{/link-to}}
</script>
```

with [Ember.Route.render](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) you can specify the `controller` to use for a template.

Note that if you want to access your AlertsModel from routes other than `alerts`, you should set up your model in the AlertsController instead. Something like this works for me with Ember 1.10, but might be slightly different for earlier version:

```
App.AlertsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    init: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.store.find('alert').then(function(model) {
            self.set('model', model);
        });
    },
    sortProperties: ['createdAt:desc'],
    sortedModel: Ember.computed.sort("model", "sortProperties"),
    remaining: function() {
            console.log(this.filterBy('isCompleted', false).get('length'));
            return this.filterBy('isCompleted', false).get('length');
    }.property('@each.isCompleted')
});
```

Comment: This does indeed get the menu template to use the alerts controller. Unfortunately, so did the code I already had. I'm accessing the "remaining" method, it's just not returning the right number. The result with this is the same, with the menu template showing 0 alerts.